# C#: How would I change the contents of a drop down list upon the change of another?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I am new to C# and am trying to learn how I would be able to change the contents of one drop down list upon the change of another? My current attempt as shown below was unsuccessful, so any advice or help would be appreciated.

```
protected void drpDwnSchool_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    drpDwnTeacher.Items.Clear();
    string selectedSchool = drpDwnSchool.SelectedValue.ToString();
    String sqlQueryTeacher = "SELECT * FROM Teacher WHERE SchoolName = '" + selectedSchool + "'";
    SqlConnection sqlConnect = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Lab1"].ToString());
    SqlCommand sqlCommand1 = new SqlCommand();
    sqlCommand1.Connection = sqlConnect;
    sqlCommand1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    sqlCommand1.CommandText = sqlQueryTeacher;
    sqlConnect.Open();
    SqlDataReader queryResultsTeacher = sqlCommand1.ExecuteReader();
    while (queryResultsTeacher.Read())
    {
        string LastName = queryResultsTeacher["LastName"].ToString();
        drpDwnTeacher.Items.Add(queryResultsTeacher["LastName"].ToString());
    }
   sqlConnect.Close();
}
```

Comment: You normally use AJAX, how would you do it if you were using a language you do know

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/009464/cascading-one-dropdownlist-with-other-dropdownlist-in-asp-ne/

Comment: You are not binding any data to `drpDwnTeacher`

Comment: remove line drpDwnTeacher.Items.Clear(); from your textcahnged event

Answer (score 0):

Is it not populating the second list? if so try the "SelectedIndexChanged" event instead of text changed.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, a few issues.

So, on page load, we assume you load up the first drop down.

```
if (IsPostBack == false)
{
    // first time page load schools
    LoadSchools();
}
```

And our code to load the combo box:

```
public void LoadSchools()
{
string strSQL = "SELECT SchoolName FROM tblSchools ORDER BY SchoolName";

this.DropDownSchools.DataSource = Myrst(strSQL);
this.DropDownSchools.DataBind();
}
```

So, on the page load, the above fills out the dropdown (combo) with the list of Schools.

Now, when you select a School?

Well, first, you need to set auto-past back for the school combo box.
Now, when a School is selected, you can now display teachers.

I would use the selected index changed, not the text change like you have.

So, that code would look like:

```
protected void DropDownSchools_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string strSQL;
strSQL = "SELECT Teacher from Teachers WHERE School = '" + 
DropDownSchools.SelectedValue + "' ORDER BY Teacher";
DropDownTeachers.DataSource = MyRst(strSQL);
DropDownTeachers.databind();

}
```

And since for every sql query you have to write for the next 10 years, and create the cmd object, the connect object and the datatable object? Well, lets save some fingers, and you can use a public routine placed in your app_code or where ever you are placing your global wide code. That routine would look like:

```
public DataTable Myrst(string strSQL, string strCon = "")
{

// this also allows one to pass custom connection string 
// - if not passed, then default

if (strCon == "") {
  strCon =
  ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("WebEasy.My.MySettings.Test3").ConnectionString;
}

SqlConnection mycon = new SqlConnection(strCon);

SqlDataAdapter oReader = new SqlDataAdapter();
DataTable rstData = new DataTable();

oReader.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(strSQL, mycon);

try
{
    oReader.Fill(rstData);
    return rstData;
}
catch
{
    return null;
}
}
```

My c# is a bit weak but the above should work.

However, we should be using parameters for this. While dropdowns are not really direct user input, as a future habit, the above code should be using parameters and not string concatenation for the sql.

What works well is to modify the above MyRst to take a sql command object in place of a string, but the above is a good start as to how you can get this type of code to work.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest way will be to set the Dropdownlist DataTextField from the HTML source as follows

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" DataTextField="YourFieldNameHere" runat="server" />
```

And also make sure that AutoPostBack is set to true on the Dropdownlist you intend to use for populating the second Dropdownlist.
While on codebehind, bind the Dropdownlist to database as below

```
protected void drpDwnSchool_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string selectedSchool = drpDwnSchool.SelectedValue.ToString();
    String sqlQueryTeacher = "SELECT * FROM Teacher WHERE SchoolName = '" + selectedSchool + "'";
    SqlConnection sqlConnect = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Lab1"].ToString());
    SqlCommand sqlCommand1 = new SqlCommand();
    sqlCommand1.Connection = sqlConnect;
    sqlCommand1.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    sqlCommand1.CommandText = sqlQueryTeacher;
    sqlConnect.Open();
    SqlDataReader queryResultsTeacher = sqlCommand1.ExecuteReader();
    if(queryResultsTeacher.HasRows){
DropDownList1.DataSource = queryResultsTeacher;
DropDownList1.DataBind();
}
   sqlConnect.Close();
}
```